# How to make pageblock section to be collapsed by default

Tags: visualforce

How to make page block section to be collapsed by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this salesforce help documentation [How to make pageblock section to be collapsed by default](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181821&language=en_US)

> NOTE: At present, this functionality cannot be implemented via
>   supported Visualforce/Apex methods. What's provided below is provided
>   "as is" and can be used at your own risk, as it makes use of a
>   function that is part of Salesforce's core JavaScript libraries, which
>   are not meant to be used by developers as they may change without
>   further notice.
>
> This can be achieved by including a script statement to show the page
>   block section collapsed by default:
>
> ```
> <apex:page >
> <apex:pageBlock id="block1">
>     <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1" columns="2" collapsible="true" title="Title">
>         Example Area
>     </apex:pageBlockSection>
>
> <script> twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0])
> ```

Comment: i am having 3 sections 2 sections section are standard page section . remaining 1 is visualforce page. i want to collapse standard page section. is it possible ?

Comment: @user33233 no you can't do with standard page section(cross site scripting not allowed )